# Generating C#/C++ Xml code documentation in a WinCE environment

Tags: c#, c++, documentation, windows-ce

I am working on a Windows CE project involving managed (C#) and unmanaged (C++) components.

For the documentation I am using Sandcastle and the Help File Builder.

My open points are the following :

1) I have not found a way to have Xml code documentation files generated from C++ code. The following option is not available for device projects :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173501(v=vs.80).aspx (the property "Generate XML Documentation Files" does not exist).

2) Assuming that there is a (fairly simple) way to generate the above required Xml files (please let me know how), would they be automatically "collected" by Sandcastle as the C# ones are and integrated consistently in the generated documentation file?

3) Is there any other way involving SandCastle to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Umberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandcastle works for.net languages. For c++, you can use Doxygen to do the same thing. (It can handle the same XML format, and output the same xml doc file)

You can also use my addin, [Atomineer Utils](http://www.atomineerutils.com) to generate and update this documentation more easily, in both c# and c++ code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since Sandcastle is a must for my customer the only solution I have found so far is to use it along with Doxygen and "link" the results even though the outcomes are graphically inconsistent.